# general setting for haptic feedback on Android

Tags: android, button

I learned that haptic feedback on a button press on Android has to be programmed individually for each button in each app.

**However, is there anywhere a general setting that one can/should access that defines if the user wants haptic feedback at all?**

Is there anything like a general setting to know how strong/long it should be?

Or has everything to be defined in the individual app - also posibly a setting that asks for haptic feedback on/off?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for View.performHapticFeedback(int feedbackConstant, int flags). You specify the the underlying event (e.g. long press) and qualifier (e.g. ignore view setting, use global setting) and you get a standard vibration which is conditioned on the global Haptic Feedback setting.

It returns true if haptic feedback actually performed.

Check the source code here for more details

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.performHapticFeedback%28int%2Cint%29